# Join Lists of Same Object Type Using Only JDK8+ Lambdas

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to join two lists of the same type (say `List<Computer> list1, list2;`) using only JDK8+ Lambdas? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Why do you want to use lambdas? What's wrong with `list1.addAll(list2)`?

Comment: `list1.addAll(list2)` will modify list1, which you may not want to do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could flatMap them to get a combined stream or list:

```
Stream<Computer> joined = Stream.of(list1, list2)
                                .flatMap(List::stream);
List<Computer> list = joined.collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively,

```
Stream<Computer> joined = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream());
```

Not sure if there is any advantage or disadvantage relative to assylias' answer. This might be easier to understand. This doesn't use any lambdas, though. I suspect OP might have meant "or streams APIs" too.

Comment: Since `Stream.concat` gets existing `Stream` instances, it has the theoretical possibility of retaining characteristics (`SIZED|SUBSIZED`, `NONNULL`, or not being `ORDERED`) if they match. However, unlike `flatMap`, it is non-lazy thus unlikely to perform well with a larger number of sub-streams, short-circuiting operations and/or memory sensitive operations in general. Afaik, the current implementation doesn’t detect nested `concat` ops and will yield in a (unbalanced) tree structure for multiple nested `concat`enated streams.